# Drag / Drop email to web browser / web upload

Tags: mail.app, email, web-browser

When I move an email out of Apple Mail to Finder, the mail will be placed as eml in this directory. Thats nice and usable. But - I want to upload some emls to a web application.

When I drag an email to a web upload field, nothing happens.

Is there any way to move an email out of Apple mail or even Outlook on Mac to the upload field of a web application? Workaround?

For Windows, there is a nice outlook plugin called dragdrop, which perfectly does the job. But - only for windows.

Can you help?

Comment: Did you try it in two steps: create file first, then upload the file?

Comment: Sure this works. But if you want to do this 100 times a day, its not very user friendly.